# Sending messages asynchronously into MongoDB using Node-Red

Tags: mongodb, node-red

New to Node-Red and just trying to understand the concept of sending messages asynchronously, using `node.send({payload:result})`

I am attempting to perform a MongoDB update with upsert based on the results being returned by the node.send() function but unfortunately I am only seeing one document insert instead of 20 documents.

My async Function A1 looks like this:

```
msg.payload.forEach(function(myRec) { 
    node.send({payload:myRec});
});
return null;
```

Using debug node, this returns all 20 documents.

My other function that is connected to this async Function A1 is being used to perform the upsert, i.e.

Function A2:

```
msg1 = {};
msg1.operation="updateOne";
msg1.collection="myCollection";

msg.myrec = msg.payload; // assuming from A1 node.send payload
msg1.payload= [
    { "myNm": "aaa"},
    { 
        $set: {
                "nm": msg.myrec.nm,
                "addressdets": msg.myrec.addressdets
             }
    },
    {upsert: true}
];    

node.send({payload:msg1});
return null;
```

Function A2 is then passed/connected to my MongoDB node within my flow.

Based on the above, the process is only inserting just one document and not the whole 20.

Any ideas as to what I am missing.

Comment: Which mongodb node are you using?

Comment: @hardillb I am using node-red-contrib-mongodb3 Are you able to let me know if I am using node.send correctly, if possible.

Comment: Nothing looks immediately wrong with the `node.send()`. What happens if you put a Delay node (in rate limit mode set to one message ever 1 second) between the function node and the mongo node. This will test if it's the mongo not node buffering incoming messages properly.

Comment: @hardillb tried the Delay node in rate limit mode and am receiving the error message from mongodb3 node of "No operation defined" but unsure why as I have msg1.operation="updateOne";

Answer (score 0):

Actually looking at this, it's wrong.

```
msg1.payload= [
    { "myNm": "aaa"},
    { 
        $set: {
                "nm": msg.myrec.nm,
                "addressdets": msg.myrec.addressdets
             }
    },
    {upsert: true}
];    

node.send({payload:msg1});
```

`node.send()` takes a msg object, but what you've passed it is an object containing a message object.

`{ payload: msg1 }` expands to:

```
{
  payload: {
    payload: [
      { "myNm": "aaa"},
      { 
        $set: {
          "nm": msg.myrec.nm,
          "addressdets": msg.myrec.addressdets
        }
      },
      {upsert: true}
    ]
  }
}
```

Change the code to the following:

```
msg1.payload= [
    { "myNm": "aaa"},
    { 
        $set: {
                "nm": msg.myrec.nm,
                "addressdets": msg.myrec.addressdets
             }
    },
    {upsert: true}
];

node.send(msg1)
```

Comment: Changed what you suggested but still only getting the one document. Not sure why the others are missed?

Comment: Still with the delay node in place?

Comment: Yes, still with the rate mode of 1 message every 1 second.